# Exporting Categories Data from Magento 2.4.2 and importing to Magento 2.4.6

Tags: magento2.4.2, magento2.4.6

I have to export categories, products and other related data from a Magento 2.4.2 instance to a empty Magento 2.4.6-p2 instance.

As the first step I am trying to export/import categories data. According to many tutorials its possible to do that via System -> Export , but Categories aren't  listed in Entities list.

Accordingly, I do appreciate if any one can suggest alternate approaches to do the needful.

Thanks and Best Regards

Indunil

Comment: Any Idea about exporting through SQL dumps,, which tables should i used for that ?

Answer (score 0):

I could do the needful via direct database table data importing, I didnt not observer any structural differences between two versions. I copied data of following tables.
[image]